# Spring Data Elastic Search with Shield

Tags: spring, elasticsearch, spring-data, spring-data-elasticsearch

Does Spring Data Elastic Search template support username and password? What are the options to if we need to use spring data to connect to elastic search that is protected with Shield.

Current configuration

```
<elasticsearch:transport-client id="client" cluster-nodes="${elasticsearch.cluster.host}:${elasticsearch.cluster.port}"
 cluster-name="${elasticsearch.cluster.name}" />

<bean name="elasticsearchTemplate" class="org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.core.ElasticsearchTemplate">
    <constructor-arg name="client" ref="client"/>
</bean>
```

Comment: I have the same problem as you. The only usefull documentation I found so far is: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/php-api/current/_security.html But this is for PHP...

If you figure it out can you please give me a heads up?

Comment: Were you able to find any solution to this problem ?

Comment: We didn't use Shield. We dropped that idea instead installed ES on EC2 instance and used it

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is currently being supported, but there is an open pull request for this feature: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-elasticsearch/pull/152