# Spring data elastic search using Shield

Tags: elasticsearch, spring-data, elastic-shield

I have the below configuration for spring data elastic search.

```
<elasticsearch:transport-client id="client" cluster-name="elasticsearch" 
    cluster-nodes="localhost:9300" />


<bean name="elasticsearchTemplate"
    class="org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.core.ElasticsearchTemplate">
    <constructor-arg name="client" ref="client" />
</bean>
```

I am planning to secure the elastic search data using Shield.

In that case, how do we change the above configuration to pass the username and password?

Comment: what "Shield" are you talking about?

Comment: check this link https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/shield/current/_using_elasticsearch_java_clients_with_shield.html

Answer (score 0):

I think this is currently not supported, but there is an open pull request: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-elasticsearch/pull/152

Also similar to [Spring Data Elastic Search with Shield](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33442604/spring-data-elastic-search-with-shield)

Comment: Thanks . But Shield needs commercial license right ?

Comment: Yes, there is a trial license, but after that you'll need a commercial license. Alternatively you can use an HTTP reverse proxy (nginx,...) or use https://cloud.elastic.co where X-Pack is included.